# QCompleter popup position

Tags: qt, qwidget, qcompleter

I'm having trouble trying to move the QCompleter popup view position.

I tried the [QCompeter:complete](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcompleter.html#complete) and it's pops the completer view in the position as I wanted.
But if I start typing it close it, and open the completer in the 'default' position.

I also tried the [QCompleter:setPopup()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcompleter.html#setPopup) function.
I create a QListView and I tried to moved to different position.
And still the QCompleter popup view remains in the same position.

In my project I'm using a QFrame that wrap QLineEdit.
And I want that the completer view will get the QFrame position.
I succeed to set the completer view width via setFixedWidth() function.
but not to move the position.

Any suggestions ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest setting the CompletionMode to InlineCompletion, so there will be no popup. Then make your QListView indepedant of the QLineEdit; just react to signals that indicate when a view types some text, leaves the QLineEdit, etc (hint: subclass QListView) and sets the text in QLineEdit when a user selects a value from the list.

I think it will be difficult to override the placement since QCompleter takes ownership of your QListView. (Personally I think it does not make much sense to place the completion list somewhere else than next to the input field, but alas...)

Comment: This helps me - I was looking for a way to make the drop-down from a (completer) combo extend to the left, since I want to show the entire word that the scroll bar may cover